# Social login using firebase in node express [Twitter , google , facebook , github ....]

Tags: node.js, express, firebase-authentication

How do i implement a single api for all the social logins ,
we are using firebase in the mobile app to authenticate , but need to store user related data in db [mongo].

And can we use jwt to authenticate the user for later requests

Tried writing an api which takes provider id and provider name , but its not secure enough . Read through the documentation of firebase , but forgive me , i didnt grasp it properly .